# Knockout inline form update method not showing updated values

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Folks

I am trying to display inline form to update records. Please see  [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2Z8Y3/25/)

`SetAcceptItem` method is working fine where I can update DB record through Ajax and After Page load modified values are displayed on screen.

> But updated values are not being observed and displayed back on
>   screen. I am not sure what is wrong here!

I want to display updated values back on screen with out page reload.

`item.update(edited.title)` in `SetAcceptItem` to update values.

```
Item = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable(data.title);
    self.searchTerm = ko.observable(data.searchTerm);
    self.update = function (data) {
        self.title(data.title);
       self.searchTerm(data.searchTerm);
    };
};
```

Ajax Code in my project

```
        data: sentData,
        success: function (data) {
            //load data
            var recData = data;
            self.item(recData);
        },
        error: function (errorMessage) {

        }
```

let me know if i need to add more details

---

> EDIT

*here is my [KO code](http://jsfiddle.net/2Z8Y3/29/) just want to know why 
            item.update(edited);is not updating values back on UI*

```
Item = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable(data.title);
    self.searchTerm = ko.observable(data.searchTerm);
    self.update = function (data) {
        self.title(data.title);
        self.searchTerm(data.searchTerm);
        alert(self.title());
    };
};

var ViewModel = function (items) {
    var self = this;

    self.items = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(items, function (data) {
        return new Item(data);
    }));

    self.TempItem ;

    //selected item
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();

    self.itemForEditing = ko.observable();

    this.GetSelectItem = function (item) {
        self.selectedItem(item);
        self.itemForEditing(new Item(ko.toJS(item)));
        //self.itemForEditing(item);
    };

    this.SetAcceptItem = function (item) {
        self.TempItem = item;
        var selected = ko.toJS(self.selectedItem());
        var edited = ko.toJS(self.itemForEditing());
        //alert(self.TempItem.title());  //edited value
        //alert(selected.title);  //old value
        //alert(edited.title); //edited value
        //alert(selected.title);  //? it is old  value
        item.update(edited);
        //write ajax query  here to udpate in database
        self.itemForEditing(null);
    };

    this.RemoveItem = function () {
        self.selectedItem(null);
        self.itemForEditing(null);
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel([{
    title: "walls",
    searchTerm: "walls1"
}, {
    title: "health",
    searchTerm: "health2"
}]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

manged to resolve Issue. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Z8Y3/31/)

using temporary objects option mentioned on  [guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html) on [knockmeout](http://www.knockmeout.net) website.

AcceptMethod is changed to something like below

1] Find requested ID in viewmodel.Array

2] if found update that array

```
this.SetAcceptItem = function (item) {
        var selected = ko.toJS(self.selectedItem());
        var edited = ko.toJS(self.itemForEditing());
        var targetId = selected.title;
        var recordFound = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.items(), function (item) {
            return item.title() == targetId;
        });

        if (recordFound) {
            recordFound.title(edited.title);
        }
        //write ajax query  here to udpate in database
        self.itemForEditing(null);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you need to call `update(data)` instead?

```
    success: function (data) {
        //load data
        var recData = data;
        self.update(recData);
    },
```